# Separate web page for more than one user

Tags: c#, .net

I build a web site that have a game. In the game the user need to see a label with a number and write the right number in text box and press check. When I open the site with 2 browsers (chrome and iexplorer), whats happen is that one continue from the second.

```
static int i = 0;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    number_lbl.Text = i + "";
}

protected void check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt16(textbox.Text) == i)
        right_wrong_lbl.Text = "right";
    else
        right_wrong_lbl.Text = "wrong";
    check.Enabled = false;
    next.Visible = true;
}

protected void next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i++;
    check.Enabled = true;
    next.Visible = false;
    number_lbl.Text = i + "";
    textbox.Text = "";
}
```

For example, I open the site in chrome and see "0", I write "0" and get "right" and click "next". I try again, see "1", write "1" and get "right" ans click "next". Now I open the site in iexplorer, see "0", write "0" and get "wrong", click "next" and see "4". If I wrote "3" in iexplorer I get "right".
How can I do that the page for each player will be indepentent in the other players' pages?

Answer (score 3):

`static` keyword before deceleration of i is causing this.
Store the value of i in a Session.

On Load:

```
if(Session["Number"]) == null)
{
     Session["Number"] = 0;
     number_lbl.Text = Session["Number"].ToString();
}
```

and replace each occurrence of i with `Session["Number"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your user isn't in a static context.
Try changing static int i to int i.

edit:

Sorry, I answered too quick.

As said in another answer here, you could store it as session variable:
Try this (I don't have any way to test it right now, but it should work):

```
int i 
{
    get
    {
       if(Session["ClickCount"] == null)
       {
          Session["ClickCount"] = 0;
       }
       return int.Parse(Session["ClickCount"].ToString());
    }
    set
    {
       Session["ClickCount"] = value;
    }
}    

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    number_lbl.Text = i + "";
}

protected void check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt16(textbox.Text) == i)
        right_wrong_lbl.Text = "right";
    else
        right_wrong_lbl.Text = "wrong";
    check.Enabled = false;
    next.Visible = true;
}

protected void next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i++;
    check.Enabled = true;
    next.Visible = false;
    number_lbl.Text = i + "";
    textbox.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: If I delete the "static" so "i" dont increase.